# Xbee and Arduino Serial Communication

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have a LCD connected to an Arduino which displays images and the image is shown on the serial if it is touched. I want to send the data written on the serial to a PC using Xbee. I have configured the Xbee modules and they are working fine.

The problem i am facing is that the data to the PC is not being sent automatically. Instead if i write something in the serial then it is being shown on the PC. The code im using is

```
 // UTFT_SdRaw_800x480_Demo
// Copyright (C)2015 Graham Lawrence (GHLawrence2000). All Rights reserved.
// web: https://github.com/ghlawrence2000/UTFT_SdRaw
//
// This program is a demo of how to use the functions provided by UTFT_SdRaw.
//
// This program requires the UTFT, UTouch, UTFT_Buttons and SdFat libraries.
//
#include <SPI.h>
// SdFat lib from here :-
// https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/archive/master.zip
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <UTFT.h>
#include <UTouch.h>
#include <UTFT_SdRaw.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];
extern uint8_t BigFont[];

#define SD_CHIP_SELECT  53  // SD chip select pin
// file system object
SdFat sd;
// print stream
SoftwareSerial XBee(10, 11); // RX, TX


// Initialize display
// ------------------
// Set the pins to the correct ones for your development board
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Standard Arduino Uno/2009 Shield            : <display model>,19,18,17,16
// Standard Arduino Mega/Due shield            : <display model>,38,39,40,41
// CTE TFT LCD/SD Shield for Arduino Due       : <display model>,25,26,27,28
// Teensy 3.x TFT Test Board                   : <display model>,23,22, 3, 4
// ElecHouse TFT LCD/SD Shield for Arduino Due : <display model>,22,23,31,33
//
// Remember to change the model parameter to suit your display module!

//UTFT myGLCD(CPLD, 38, 39, 40, 41);
//UTFT myGLCD(CTE50, 38, 39, 40, 41);
UTFT myGLCD(CTE70, 38, 39, 40, 41);


// Initialize touchscreen
// ----------------------
// Set the pins to the correct ones for your development board
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Standard Arduino Uno/2009 Shield            : 15,10,14, 9, 8
// Standard Arduino Mega/Due shield            :  6, 5, 4, 3, 2
// CTE TFT LCD/SD Shield for Arduino Due       :  6, 5, 4, 3, 2
// CTE TFT LCD/SD Shield for Arduino Due (JP10):  6, 5,32, 3, 2
// Teensy 3.x TFT Test Board                   : 26,31,27,28,29
// ElecHouse TFT LCD/SD Shield for Arduino Due : 25,26,27,29,30
//
UTouch  myTouch(6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

UTFT_SdRaw myFiles(&myGLCD);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  XBee.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for DUE & Leonardo only
  }
  Serial.println(F("Initialising SD card..."));
  bool mysd = 0;
  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  while (!mysd) {
    if (!sd.begin(SD_CHIP_SELECT, SPI_FULL_SPEED)) {
      Serial.println(F("Card failed, or not present"));
      Serial.println(F("Retrying...."));
    } else {
      mysd = 1;
      Serial.println(F("Card initialised."));
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("Initialising LCD."));
  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont);
  myTouch.InitTouch();
  myTouch.setPrecision(PREC_MEDIUM);
  Serial.println(F("LCD initialised."));
  myGLCD.clrScr();
  myFiles.load(0, 0, 800, 480, "lcd1.raw", 2, 0);
}

byte dispScreen = 1;  // Currently displayed screen, screens shown below                                        //
// 1-home, 2-lights, , 3-temp, 4-fogger, 5-mister, 6-fan, 7-clock, 8-screen                                     //

void processMyTouch() {
  myTouch.read();
  int x = myTouch.getX();
  int y = myTouch.getY();
  switch (dispScreen) { //                                                                                        //
    //                                                                                                          //
    case 1:  // home screen                                                                                     //

      // do stuff here for screen 1

      if ((x > 650 && x < 800) && (y > 20 && y < 460)) {
        //button 'back'
        myGLCD.clrScr();
        dispScreen = 2; // <======================================= change screen each time you go to a new screen
        myFiles.load(0, 0, 800, 480, "lcd_2.raw", 2, 0);
      }
      if ((x > 19 && x < 340) && (y > 21 && y < 212)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println("Drinks");

      }
      if ((x > 400 && x < 5700) && (y > 21 && y < 212)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("Food"));
      }

      if ((x > 19 && x < 340) && (y > 240 && y < 448)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("Tea"));
      }

      if ((x > 400 && x < 550) && (y > 240 && y < 448)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("Water"));
      }


      break;

    case 2:

      // do stuff here for screen 2


      if ((x > 170 && x < 430) && (y > 21 && y < 212)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("news"));
      }

      if ((x > 17 && x < 100) && (y > 30 && y < 400)) {
        //button 'news'
        myGLCD.clrScr();
        dispScreen = 1; // <======================================= change screen each time you go to a new screen
        myFiles.load(0, 0, 800, 480, "lcd1.raw", 2, 0);
      }

      if ((x > 530 && x < 750) && (y > 21 && y < 212)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("light."));
      }

      if ((x > 530 && x < 750) && (y > 240 && y < 448)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("Blanket"));
      }

      if ((x > 170 && x < 430) && (y > 240 && y < 448)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println(F("Medic"));
      }


      break;

  }
}


unsigned long prevMillisTouch = 0; // track time between touches                                                //
unsigned long TouchRepeatDelay = 500; // millis                                                                 //

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); // get current millis                                                 //
  if (myTouch.dataAvailable())  { //                                                                            //
    //                     make sure it's been .5 sec (initially) between touches                               //
    if (currentMillis - prevMillisTouch > TouchRepeatDelay) {                                                   //
      //                                                                                                        //
      prevMillisTouch = currentMillis; // reset the touch timer                                                 //
      processMyTouch();                                                                                         //
    } //                                                                                                        //
  } //  

 //
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // If data comes in from serial monitor, send it out to XBee
    XBee.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (XBee.available()) {
    // If data comes in from XBee, send it out to serial monitor
    Serial.write(XBee.read());
  }
}
```

Example:

```
if ((x > 19 && x < 340) && (y > 21 && y < 212)) {
        //button 'news'
        Serial.println("Drinks");
```

'Drinks" is displayed on the serial if i touch the above coordinates. However, the data is not sent to the other Xbee module. if i manually write drinks in the serial, it shows on the other Xbee module.

Any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You need `XBee.println("Drinks");` instead of `Serial.println("Drinks");` to send the string 'Drinks' to the other XBee module.

`Serial.println` will write text only on the local console, and `XBee.println` will only send data to the other XBee. If you want data to be sent and displayed on the console you will need to call both functions.

**Long answer:**

```
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // If data comes in from serial monitor, send it out to XBee
    XBee.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

This portion of the code reads whatever you write on the serial console and sends it the Xbee.

```
  if (XBee.available()) {
    // If data comes in from XBee, send it out to serial monitor
    Serial.write(XBee.read());
  }
```

This portion of the code reads whatever is received on the Xbee and writes it to the serial console.

`Serial` is the connection between your PC and arduino. `XBee` is the connection between arduino and the XBee. Manually writing text in the console works because the first chunk of code re-transmits what you have written to the XBee by calling the `XBee.write` function. If you want to send data to XBee you need to call `XBee.write`/`XBee.println` functions.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, it works.  However, now i am trying to show the data on the xbee on a LCD. I am using an i2c port with the LCD. I am trying to use the function lcd.write(XBee.read()); function but it only shows black boxes on the lcd. I used the lcd.print("test") and it works. How can i use the lcd.write function

Comment: @shayaan123 This is most likely happening because you are using software serial for your Xbee. Software serial is unable to capture characters correctly since the arduino is busy writing the previous character to the lcd.

Comment: Yes i am using a software serial. Is there a way to fix this. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @shayaan123 Read the string you receive in an array and write to lcd from array when there is no incoming data from the Xbee.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. Can you give an example which i can alter for my code.